# Flutter Firestore save field as a String?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a problem with Flutter and Firebase Firestore. I want to take one of the current User's label, and save it as a string. I have already figured out how to find the currentUserID, so that isn't the problem. I just can't figure out how to target the "preference" label in my database. Here is my code for trying to declare it as a string:

```
String _checkPreference(DocumentSnapshot document) {
  Firestore.instance.collection(currentUserId).document('preference').toString();

  return _checkPreference(document);
  }
```

The goal is then later to be able to do something like this:

```
  return Text(_checkPreference(document));
```

Bit I am not really sure what to pass in, and if my method to get it is even correct. Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated!

Comment: From document path u cannot get text. U should retrieve it as parameter from it.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I haven't been able to find anything about that. Thanks!

Comment: As per my understanding, you want fields from a document in some path. But you are not mentioning in ur code which parameter it is. Example: document[“field name”]

Comment: I tried that aswell, but I am struggling to target the currentuser. Even when I wrote .collection(CurrentUserID).document['preference'], I couldnt get it to work... But I will look into it further, and thank you for your messages.

Comment: Are u able to get current user